# navigator.onLine always returning true in electron

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

I am developing an application using React and electron. I am planning to check the internet connection of the user. For this, navigator.online is used. However, even if I disconnect my internet connection, it always turns true and shows as if there is a connection. What I want to do is to pull data from an api if there is a connection, but to pull data from a json file. How can I check another way if the user has an internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-online

Just import the `isOnline` function and then you can call it like this:

```
const isOnline = require('is-online');

...

isOnline().then(online => {
  console.log(`Online? ${online}`);
  ...
}
```

Comment: **This will not work!** `is-online` is an esm package. These cannot be directly used by electron right now. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21457